# Routes not return the index page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a filename create.blade.php inside the views/articles folder.
With my following route I need to call this page but I am getting page not found message.

```
Route::get('/article/create', 'ArticleController@create');
```

### controller

```
public function index()
{
    //Get articles
    $articles = Article::select('id','title','body', 'created_at')
                        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                        ->get();
    // return data
    return view('articles.index')->with('articles', json_decode($articles));
}

public function create() 
{
    return view('articles.create');
}
```

### routes

```
//List Single Article
Route::get('article/{id}', 'ArticleController@show');
Route::get('/article/create', 'ArticleController@create');
```

Comment: Show us the code of your ArticleController's `index` method.

Comment: Show the whole routes maybe you have a prior route of `Route::get('/article/{slug}', 'ArticleController@show');`

Comment: **If** you do `Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController')` after that declaration then you'll be overwriting your route. I don't know if that is what is happening here because that code snippet is not enough to go by

Comment: @SandOfVegaI have updated my question

Comment: Ideally, `/article/create` would point to the `create()` method (`ArticleController@create`) and use the `resources/views/articles/create.blade.php` view. Make sure your route is actually available (`php artisan route:list`) and that you didn't accidentally type `/articles/create`

Comment: @kerbholz But create method is also not being called.

Comment: post create.blade.php code here.may be you are missing csrf..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route

```
Route::get('article/create', 'ArticleController@create');
```

And You can specify all CRUD methods using single resource route

```
Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController');
```

And if still it doesnt work (Just Assuming) Add your route in your `VerifyCsrfToken.php` file in `App\Http\Middleware`

```
protected $except = [
 'article/create',
 // other routes
];
```

Comment: can you try running command `composer dump-autoload` and then try?

Comment: did you used `Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController')` ? if yes then you dont need to specify new route for create method

Comment: Thank You @leena I better use Route::resource